# Maximizing a submodular function with restricted values

Tags: approximation-algorithms, submodularity

Maximizing a general monotone submodular function $f$ under the constraint that $|S|\leq k$, can be approximated to $(1-1/e)$.  I am wondering if a better approximation algorithm exists if the function $f$ has these additional properties for any element $x$ and subset $S$:

1. $f(\{x\}) \in \{0, 1, 2\}$
2. $f(S \cup \{x\}) - f(S) \in \{0, 1, 2\}$

or even the more restricted properties :

3. $f(\{x\}) \in \{0, 1\}$
4. $f(S \cup \{x\}) - f(S) \in \{0, 1\}$

Comment: Note that (1) implies (2) (assuming $f(\emptyset) = 0$) since $f(S \cup \{x\}) \leq f(S) + f(\{x\})$. (That's assuming that the function is integer-valued.)

Comment: (3) implies (4). If a monotone $f$ satisfies (3) then it is essentially the rank function of a matroid $M$ (we can suppress the elements $x$ with $f(x) = 0$). Maximizing $f$ subject to a cardinality constraint is the same as finding min of $k$ and the rank of $M$ which is poly-time solvable.